# what's best branching stragegy for this scenario?

Tags: git, branch

Let's say I have Master branch M and Feature branch F. Both branches are under continuous development. For the next release going production, I only want everything that is in M. Until then there will be daily releases to test environment that include both material from M and F.

Currently I have F branched off M. Every day deploying to Test, I would rebase F branch to M first, and deploy F. This has been pretty good until I had to do manual merges on conflicts. To be honest I am not sure exactly how rebase works. Sometimes I feel like I am resolving the same conflict multiple times in the same session. It seems the longer I keep the 2 branches separate the more I have to resolve the same conflicts for each time I rebase. It seems it could help if I keep editing the same set of files each branch, but sometimes that's not realistic. You need to do what you need to do to complete a feature, right?

What is a good strategy for this scenario?

Comment: If F is a feature branch, I'd expect it to be short lived and with quite a small number of commits. Thus rebasing working quite easily. Maybe a workaround can be to reduce the number of commits on F? Using squashing for instance.

Comment: If you need to resolve multiple time the same conflicts you might want to use git rerere
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible you *are* having to resolve the same conflicts. Rebasing creates a new commit for each commit in your branch. That is, it turns something like

```
m1 -- m2 -- m3 (M)
 \
  f1 -- f2 -- f3 (F)
```

into

```
m1 -- m2 -- m3 (M) -- f1' -- f2' -- f3' (F)
```

If there is a conflict introduced by `f1`, you would have to correct it in order to create `f1'`, but then you may have to correct it again to create `f2'`, and so on.

The alternative is to merge M into F, yielding

```
m1 -- m2 -- m3 ----- (M)
  \                 \
   f1 -- f2 -- f3 -- * (F)
```

Now any conflicts need to be resolved only once, when the new commit `*` is created. `f1` through `f3` remain unchanged, rather than each being replaced by a corresponding new commit.

If it turns out `F` is ready to be merged into `M`, you have again only need to create a single new commit (which should be conflict-free since `*` has already resolved them):

```
m1 -- m2 -- m3 ----+--- ** (M)
  \                 \ /
   f1 -- f2 -- f3 -- * (F)
```

To be clear, `**` has two parents: `*` and `m3`. `*` also has two parents: `m3` and `f3`.

There is also the `rerere` command, which can be used to "replay" the same fix made to create `f1'` when creating `f2'`. I'll refer you to `git help rerere` rather than (poorly) recapping it here. (`rerere` is also useful for avoiding multiple "artificial" merge commits in `F`; again see the help for a discussion on that topic.)